# Cannot connect to Oracle Cloud Compute VM instance with PUTTY

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I launched an instance and trying to connect using Putty. But I am getting the error "Network error: Connection timeout".

[image: network-error]

I did the following steps.

1. Open putty.exe.
2. In the Category pane, select Session and enter the following:

   Host Name (or IP address):

   opc@131.xx.xx.xx

   Port: 22

   Connection type: SSH
3. In the Category pane, expand Connection, expand SSH, and then click Auth.
4. Click Browse, and then select your private key.
5. Click Open to start the session.

My security lists of VCN looks like below.

[image: security lists]

**Any inputs?**

Comment: Are you using a VPN?

Comment: No, I am using laptop in corporate domain

Comment: If you open the command prompt in Windows, can you execute ping 8.8.8.8 for example? You might still be inside the corporate network and need to set the proxy for PuTTY.

Comment: I pinged 8.8.8.8 and it is 100% loss. Does it mean I am under proxy? Although i did not see any proxy in my LAN settings.

Comment: Sounds like it. Ask internally or if your browser lets you download this file: `http://wpad/wpad.dat` , that can show you any proxy servers used. Then you can use a proxy [like this](https://superuser.com/questions/351560/use-putty-behind-a-proxy).

Comment: There are so many servers listed. Additionally, I noted one thing, using WiFi I am able to connect to the instance where as with LAN I am not able to.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61375652/oracle-cloud-instance-connectivity-issue

Answer (score 2):

Does you VCN routing table has 0.0.0.0/0 CIDR with target of "Internet Gateway"? Did you create "Internet Gateway"?

Answer (score 1):

If you have manually created the VCN and Route tables make your VCN have the Internet gateway and route table rules.

**0.0.0.0/0** in route rules

[image]

You can check for the **Network security group** to allow the SSH port.

Comment: This was absurd, but I just had to go through all this. Create a security list, route table, internet gateway, network security group, and security list. I must have clicked the wrong thing, because some tutorials showing this working without all this setup. But finally I am able to SSH in!

Comment: Yes understand your point and issue but this is what worked for me for many other but glad to hear solved for you too.

Comment: To be fair, it is a different beast than some other providers. Requires a much more hands-on approach. Oracle approached it from a maximum security and do-it-yourself standpoint. I can appreciate that, particularly for some of their large corporate clients. For free-tier smucks like me, it caused a major learning experience after coming from Linode!

Comment: Indeed you are right, when coming from different providers it's a little hard to configure. Need more hands-on ideas about default configuration, unlike route rules that come set by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your LAN DHCP is probably giving out an automatic proxy configuration. Just check the proxy setting and disable any kind, including automatic configuration.

Then you should easily be able to SSH into your session.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out what proxy is being used in your network (you could use http://whatismyip.com)
   2.Try to use that proxy on putty to connect to the instance

Answer (score 0):

check the used(downloaded during compute instance creation) private key is in .key format or not. If yes, the use PuTTYgen to convert it as a .ppk private key.